# override table column alignment in individual cells and rows

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

In this example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
  00pad & 01pad & 02pad\\
  10 & 11 & 12\\
  20 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{21} & 22\\
  30 & 31 & 32\\
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{40} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{41} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{42}\\
  50 & 51 & 52\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I have overridden the column alignment in cell 21 and row 4. The result is:

[image]

Is using `\multicolumn` the most efficient and simple macro to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `makecell`  is slightly shorter – and it allows you to have multiline cells in this context. By default, it is vertically and horizontally centred, but it can be changed with the optional argument which can contain up to 2 letters each in the groups `r, l, c` and `t, b, c`.

Demo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l l l}
  00pad & 01pad & 02pad\\
  10 & 11 & 12\\
  20 & \makecell[r]{21} & 22\\
  30 & 31 & 32\\
  \makecell[r]{40} & \makecell[r]{41} & \makecell[r]{42\\43}\\
  50 & 51 & 52\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your example I would not use `\multicolumn`, because a simple `\hfill` will do (for right-aligned cell).

[image: hfilled]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
  00pad & 01pad & 02pad\\
  10 & 11 & 12\\
  20 & \hfill 21 & 22\\
  30 & 31 & 32\\
    \hfill 40 & \hfill 41 & \hfill 42\\
  50 & 51 & 52\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What if I wanted to override left alignment with centring?

Comment: You could use `\hfill 21 \hfill`.